# userInteractionEnabled isn't disabling touch events

Tags: ios

I am trying to disable touch events for my game's UIView, but setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO` doesn't seem to have any effect.  This is the only view I have in the App.

If I check `isUserInteractionEnabled` for the view, it returns NO.

I am getting my `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event` messages via my UIViewController, not the UIView.  Since adding a root UIViewController, I no longer get touch events sent to the UIView.

Am I doing something wrong here?  I would assume setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO` would stop all touch events from happening.

Comment: Try setting also viewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 0):

For some components if you uncheck User Interaction Enabled in interface builder, the component will actually ignore that setting. UITextView is an example of this behavior. The way I have found around the issue is to explicitly set userInteractionEnabled to NO within the awakeFromNib method, and the initWithFrame method. Subclass Example;

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if(self) {
        [self setup];
    }
}
-(void) setup {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```